# Sobrecarga de operador no me retorna bien

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Tengo creada una clase Matriz, con atributos: `int filas`, `int columnas` y `double** matriz`.

Mi duda es que tengo sobrecargado el operador "-" para que me reste dos matrices y no se muy bien que retorna cuando hago *c=a-b* (siendo *a*, *b* y *c* objetos creados de la clase Matriz) y al hacer `c.imprimir()` no me imprime nada (los constructores y el metodo imprimir no los pongo porque ya he comprobado que esten bien).

Os dejo por aqui el codigo del operador sobrecargado "=" (constructor copia) y del operador sobrecargado "-".

```
Matriz& Matriz::operator-( Matriz& m)
{
    Matriz resultado(m.n_filas, m.n_columnas);

    for (int i = 0; i < resultado.n_filas; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < resultado.n_columnas; j++) {

            resultado.matriz[i][j] = this->matriz[i][j] - m.matriz[i][j];
            cout << "resultado["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] = "<<resultado.matriz[i][j] << endl;
        }

    }

    resultado.mostrarMatriz();
    return resultado;
}
Matriz& Matriz::operator= (const Matriz& m)
{
    if (matriz != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_filas; i++)
            delete[] matriz[i];

        delete[] matriz;
        matriz = NULL;
    }

    this->n_filas = m.n_filas;
    this->n_columnas = m.n_columnas;
    this->matriz = NULL;
    if (n_filas > 0 && n_columnas > 0)
    {
        matriz = new double* [n_filas];

        for (int i = 0; i < n_filas; i++)
        {
            matriz[i] = new double[n_columnas];
            for (int j = 0; j < n_columnas; j++)
                matriz[i][j] = m.matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

    return(*this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu operador de resta está conceptualmente mal.

---

Cuando restas dos números:

> C = A - B

El resultado no es ninguno de los números originales, es decir, *C* no es ni *A* ni es *B*, es "*un número nuevo*". Al operar sobre otros tipos (como matrices) sucede lo mismo.

Por lo tanto, no puedes devolver una **referencia** a matriz en la resta, debe ser una matriz nueva:

```
// Instancia, no referencia (&), const porque no modifica el objeto original ni el proveído
Matriz Matriz::operator-(const Matriz& m)  const
{
    Matriz resultado(m.n_filas, m.n_columnas);

    for (int i = 0; i < resultado.n_filas; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < resultado.n_columnas; j++) {

            resultado.matriz[i][j] = this->matriz[i][j] - m.matriz[i][j];
            cout << "resultado["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] = "<<resultado.matriz[i][j] << endl;
        }

    }

    resultado.mostrarMatriz();
    return resultado;
}
```

Normalmente estas operaciones se redactan como operadores libres, no como operadores miembro:

```
Matriz operator-(const Matriz &a, const Matriz &b)
{
    Matriz resultado( … );

    // … operaciones

    return resultado;
}
```

Tu código estaba generando un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) porque estabas devolviendo una referencia a un objeto que ya no existía.

Comment: la sobrecarga tiene que ser un metodo de la clase matriz,lo que tu me dices solo podria ponerlo en el main no?

Comment: No, la sobrecarga no **tiene que ser** un método de la clase, puede ser externo. En general, se implementan los operadores binarios externamente. Se podrá usar siempre y cuando sea visible desde el punto de uso (igual que la clase).

Comment: A lo que me referia es que nos piden hacerlo como metodo de la clase,por eso no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo ya que todo lo que pruebo acaba petando

Comment: Si os piden hacerlo dentro de la clase, no creo que estén enseñando bien. Por otro lado ¿Qué es exactamente lo que te está fallando?

Answer (score -1):

Respuesta editada después de leer los comentarios a la respuesta:

El problema es que estás retornando una referencia a un objeto que creas dentro de la función del operador, que se destruye al salir de la función. Con lo que fuera, la referencia ya no es válida.

Se me ocurre que en vez de una referencia, retornes el propio objeto Matriz que has creado en el operador y que contiene la suma de las dos matrices. El prototipo de la función sería algo así:

```
Matriz Matriz::operator-( const Matriz& m) const
```

El resto de la función no cambia.

Comment: La matriz recibida como parámetro debería ser `const`, también el operador

Comment: Cierto. No había caído.

Comment: Yo tampoco caí al principio, pero para eso están las ediciones :P